# dpkg error when trying to install mysql-server

Tags: raspbian, server, mysql, lighttpd

I'm running a lighttpd web server on my Pi and I'm trying to add php and mysql support. I'm currently trying to install mysql-server with the command

> 'sudo apt-get install mysql-server'

which results in the following error:

```
[my user name]@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libhtml-template-perl mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libhtml-template-perl mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
  mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,938 kB of archives.
After this operation, 46.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libaio1 mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 libhtml-template-perl
  mysql-server
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaio1:armhf.
(Reading database ... 121517 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libaio1_0.3.110-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libaio1:armhf (0.3.110-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.52-0+deb8u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 10.0 to 5.5.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.5, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-template-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhtml-template-perl_2.95-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (2.95-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.5.52-0+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I know the same problem was reported here:
[Raspberry PI 2: Installing mysql-server](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28312/raspberry-pi-2-installing-mysql-server)

But the solution in that case seemed to be enabling the loopback interface. In my case, the loopback interface is working fine but that doesn't solve my problem.

ifconfig output:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1096 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1096 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:91408 (89.2 KiB)  TX bytes:91408 (89.2 KiB)
```

I tried the following commands, repeatedly, with no result:

> 'sudo apt-get -f install'
>
> 'sudo apt-get autoremove'
>
> 'sudo apt-get autoclean'
>
> 'sudo apt-get update'
>
> 'sudo apt-get upgrade'
>
> 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'

Comment: It may be the insufficient space problem on your SD card.

Comment: Please provide the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list' file.

Answer (score 1):

### Key Authentication and Downgrade

You have two concerning error messages:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
```

and

```
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 10.0 to 5.5.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.5, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

The first message indicates that the key used to sign those packages are not on your keyring.  This is a bit mysterious and indicates possible issues with your repository configuration.

The second message indicates that you already have a newer version of `mysql-server` installed, and that it conflicts with the older version, so they can't both be installed at the same time.  You'll have to uninstall the newer version first.

I believe that version 10.0 is the `mariadb` version of mysql, whereas 5.5 is the older `mysql` version of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `apt-key update` as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/75575/590737) followed by `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` ?

Comment: Here is the output:
    [username]@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-key update
    [sudo] password for [username]:
    ERROR: Can't find the archive-keyring
    Is the debian-archive-keyring package installed?